# Drop down menu is not collapsing and displayed correctly in Chrome and MF

Tags: java, javascript, internet-explorer, jsp, google-chrome

I have a little bit of a problem...The site that i am working on has been working perfectly fine in IE....I was asked to fix a couple of problems and make it work in Chrome and Mozilla Firefox. My main problem right now is that a dropdown menu is not displayed correctly in Chrome and Mozilla (only opens half of the content) and after you hover the cursor off it, the menu doest collapse entirely...

Maybe some of you could spot something from just looking at this:

I GREATLY APPRECIATE YOUR TIME! THANKS A LOT!

**Javascript:**

```
var DDSPEED = 10;
var DDTIMER = 15;
var OFFSET = -2;
var ZINT = 100;
function ddMenu(id,d){
  var h = document.getElementById(id + '-ddheader');
  var c = document.getElementById(id + '-ddcontent');
  clearInterval(c.timer);
  if(d == 1){
    clearTimeout(h.timer);
    c.style.display = 'block';
    if(c.maxh && c.maxh <= c.offsetHeight){return}
    else if(!c.maxh){
      c.style.left = (h.offsetWidth + OFFSET) + 'px';
      c.style.height = 'auto';
      c.maxh = c.offsetHeight;
      c.style.height = '0px';     
    }
    ZINT = ZINT + 1;
    c.style.zIndex = ZINT;
    c.timer = setInterval(function(){ddSlide(c,1)},DDTIMER);
    h.style.backgroundColor='#D4D4D4';
      h.style.borderBottom='1px solid #b9d6dc';
  }else{
    h.style.backgroundColor='white';
    h.style.borderBottom='0px solid white';
    h.timer = setTimeout(function(){ddCollapse(c)},50);
  } 
}
function ddCollapse(c){
  c.timer = setInterval(function(){ddSlide(c,-1)},DDTIMER);
}
function cancelHide(id){
  var h = document.getElementById(id + '-ddheader');
  var c = document.getElementById(id + '-ddcontent');
  clearTimeout(h.timer);
  clearInterval(c.timer);
  if(c.offsetHeight < c.maxh){
    c.timer = setInterval(function(){ddSlide(c,1)},DDTIMER);
  }
}
```

**Stylesheet:**

```
* {padding:0; margin:0}

#wrapper {width:150px; padding:4px; margin:0 auto;font:10px; color:#66C;}
#leftcolumn {float:right; width:125px}
#rightcolumn {float:right; width:125px}
.main {width:160px; text-align:right; padding:2px;}
.main a, main a:active, .main a:visited {color:#036; border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF; }
.main a:hover {background-color:#D4D4D4; color:#399}

.dropdown {display:block; position:relative}
.dropdown dt {width:160px; text-align:right;color:#036; cursor:pointer;padding:2px; }
.dropdown .upperdd { text-align:right;border-bottom:none;}
.dropdown dt:hover {color:#399;}
.dropdown dd {position:absolute; padding-bottom:2px; top:0; overflow:hidden; display:none;  width: auto; opacity:150; border: 1px solid #036;}
.dropdown ul {width:90px;  list-style:none; opacity:150;}
.dropdown li {display:inline;opacity:150;}
.dropdown a, .dropdown a:active, .dropdown a:visited {display:block; padding-left:4px; background-color:#F1F1F1; width:174px;padding:2px;}
.dropdown a:hover {background-color:#D4D4D4; color:#399;}
.dropdown .underline {border-bottom:1px solid #036;}
```

**JSP**

```
<dl class="dropdown">
    <dt id="two-ddheader" class="upperdd" onmouseover="ddMenu('two',1)" onmouseout="ddMenu('two',-1)">Dash-Board</dt>
    <dd id="two-ddcontent" onmouseover="cancelHide('two')" onmouseout="ddMenu('two',-1)">
```